# How do I get the power series for $\frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

How do I get the power series for $\frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}$ around $z=0$?
I know the answer is:
$\sum_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}nz^{n+1}$, for $|z|<1$ and $\sum_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}nz^{-n+2}$, for $|z|>1$. I've tried using the geometric series and working the expressions but getting the $n$ before the $z^n$ is impossible doing that. So I have no idea on how to do this. Any help?

Comment: $$\frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}=-z^2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac1{1+z}\right)=-z^2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^n\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: Use $f(z)=f(0)+zf'(0)+\frac{z^2}{2!}.f''(0)+$...

Comment: @mathlover Did you actually tried to follow this suggestion? For example, how would you compute $f^{(42)}(0)$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}nz^{-n+2}=z-2+{3\over z}-{4\over z^2}+\cdots$ for $|z|\gt1$ can't be correct, since $z^2/(1+z)^2\to1$, not $\infty$, as $z\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well-known that the power series of  $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{1+z}$ is:

$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{1+z}=\dfrac{1}{1-(-z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n.$$
By taking the derivative we obtain

$$f'(z)=\dfrac{-1}{(1+z)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n nz^{n-1}$$

and finally, we multiply by $-z^2$ in both sides to get

$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}&=(-z^2)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\cdot n\cdot z^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n\cdot z^{(n-1)+2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n\cdot z^{n+1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Its clear now! Thanks!

Comment: Just something else, how would you go about calculating the same thing but for $|z| > 1$ ?